# Посчитать минимальное количество комбинаций

Tags: python, for

Сразу к делу:

```
n = int(input())
```

Ввожу число и у меня есть 2 команды:

```
+ 1
* 2
```

Начальное значение `a = 1`, так вот с помощью этих команд за минимальное кол-во ходов нужно получить `n`, не подскажите как это сделать
Протокол:

```
Input        Output
  11            5   
   3            2
```

***В первом примере:**

```
1 * 2 = 2
2 * 2 = 4
4 + 1 = 5
5 * 2 = 10
10 + 1 = 11 #  5 ходов
```

***Во втором примере:**

```
1 * 2 = 2
2 + 1 = 3 #  2 хода
```

Comment: Начинать нужно с `n` и двигаться к `1`, предпочитая деление вычитанию

Comment: Учесть что выводить порядок не надо. То число единичных бит в числе плюс число всех разрядов числа минус два) я думаю есть встроенные функции для этого.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
n = 11

counter = 0
while n > 1:
    if n & 0x1 == 0:
        n //= 2
    else:
        n -= 1
    counter += 1

print(counter)  # 5
```

Можно с выводом всех вычислений:

```
n = 10
a = 1
stack = []

counter = 0
while n > a:
    if n & 0x1 == 0:
        n //= 2
        stack.append(2)
    else:
        n -= 1
        stack.append(1)
    counter += 1

print(counter)

while stack:
    operator = stack.pop()
    if operator == 2:
        print('{0:d} * 2 = {1:d}'.format(a, a * 2))
        a *= 2
    else:
        print('{0:d} + 1 = {1:d}'.format(a, a + 1))
        a += 1

# 4
# 1 * 2 = 2
# 2 * 2 = 4
# 4 + 1 = 5
# 5 * 2 = 10
```